# Grails criteria running too slow

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

the following criteria is running unacceptably slow. Without entering into too much detail on the table's primary keys or indexes, do you see anything particular that could make this run faster?

```
def results = OpportunityApplication.createCriteria().list() {

            isNull('dateDeleted')

            or {
                opportunityInst {
                    isNull('dateDeleted')
                    opportunity {
                        isNull('dateDeleted')
                        gt('advertisingEndDate', new Date())
                        eq('useOrgAsContact', false)
                    }
                    opportunityLocation {
                        isNull('dateDeleted')
                        eq("email", user.email)
                    }
                }

                if (isPartner)
                {
                    opportunityInst {
                        isNull('dateDeleted')
                        opportunity {
                            isNull('dateDeleted')
                            gt('advertisingEndDate', new Date())
                            eq('useOrgAsContact', true)
                            organisation {
                                isNull('dateDeleted')
                                eq("email", user.email)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about your database or requirements, all I can suggest is that you delete lots of data from the DB or remove lots of predicates from the query

Comment: @Don That's hardly constructive, but I fully agree that he needs to post the db schema.

Comment: If you turn on SQL logging, you can get the generated query and run `EXPLAIN` on it. That would be better than just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimization to my criteria was quite straight forward. All I had to do was to move around the repeated bits into a shared snippet as follows

```
opportunityInst {
                isNull('dateDeleted')
                opportunity {
                    isNull('dateDeleted')
                    gt('advertisingEndDate', new Date())
                }
                or {
                    if (isPartner)
                    {
                        opportunity {
                            eq('useOrgAsContact', true)
                            organisation {
                                isNull('dateDeleted')
                                eq("email", user.email)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    and {
                        opportunity {
                            eq('useOrgAsContact', false)
                        }
                        opportunityLocation {
                            isNull('dateDeleted')
                            eq("email", user.email)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```